# /var/spool/mail and /var/mail/root same inode but just one link count

Tags: linux, bash, hardlink

i found something on my linux systems i don't understand.

The files /var/spool/mail/root and /var/mail/root point to the same inode but the link count is 1. This is the same on a ubuntu and a centos server.

When i create hardlinks to a file the hardlink count increases with every new file.

Why is the link count just one?

Answer (score 1):

That is because /var/mail is a symbolic link to /var/spool/mail.

Comment: ... and the link count would only count "hard links", not symoblic ones